# How to get my stomach Abs in shape without using any machine work outs & following only home based work outs?

Tags: abdominals

How to get my abs in shape without using any machine work outs, following only home based work outs?

There are plenty of articles online discussing abs, which also point to using machines or weights ..

I wonder, exercises like planks, sit ups & so on for my abs.

Comment: Do your research... Most ab machines aren't even worth doing. Waste of time. There are hundreds of body weight and home exercises you can do without any weights or equipment at all...

Comment: @Twyxz , thank you .. that is exactly i am looking for .. without using the machines.. from home.. what i can do to improve my abs ..

Comment: if you even searched "Home ab workout" and actually did it consistently with high quality execution. Alongside a good diet, your abs will develop.

Comment: While it's not 100% true that "Abs are made in the kitchen, not the gym," since it does take exercise, most people need pretty low body fat to make their abs visible, and that's difficult to do without caloric reduction.

Comment: Try looking (googling) at the ab-routines in P90X and X3, those are great, consists of approximately 8 different routines none of the involving any equipment. The X3 version is a bit more “modern” not relaying too much on sit-ups (which is considered a bit old school by now).

Comment: @ssn .. thank you.. for the tips.. i am hearing it for the first time in my life about P90X, P90X3 .. looks like . i need to buy some equipments... but thats okay.. i will do that .. thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Jwrecker, and I would add hollow body holds to that. Also, it's really essential to focus on contracting your abs, as you may find yourself initiating the movement with your hip flexors if you don't pay close attention.

On a broader note, abs are 90% diet and 10% ab training -- it doesn't really matter how much muscle you have if you can't see it. If you want to get abs, it's really key to eat less and do a high amount of high intensity exercise like resistance & power training to maintain a caloric deficit and therefore reduce your bodyfat %. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you @Tyler .. i cant imagine 90% diet .. , but anyways.. i will go with it :)

Comment: Of course, everything has to be taken into account, but generally if you're not at a low bodyfat % then it's pretty difficult to get defined abs even with good training. (as a side note, my abs started developing after I lost some weight, which I owe to eating a leaner diet)

Comment: that makes sense.. i will watch.. what i am gonna eat .. , what it tells me that i cant eat anything that tastes good .. sad , but thats okay

Comment: @SelfOptimizationNerd it's easy to get defined abs without diet. It's hard to see them, however, without diet. :)

Answer (score 1):

the best way to improve your abs at home doesn't necessarily exist, there probably isn't one sure way. However, I try to do a variety of ab exercises that use no equipment other than your body. Sit-ups, Crunches, V-ups, Leg Lifts, and more, but make sure to use a variety to work out all of the abs and you can get that 6-pack you want.

Comment: Thank you @Jwrecker..  and welcome to stackoverflow :)